# How can I get code example from 'Moving to Visual Studio 2010' working?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Using code example in free ebook Moving to visual studio 2010. I am unable to get the code to run. Getting error copied in below.

The code example and ebook is downloadable here

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/microsoft_press/free-ebook-moving-to-microsoft-visual-studio-2010?PageIndex=11#comments)

This is the code I am trying to get to run: 'the correct solution can be found at Documents\Microsoft Press\Moving to Visual Studio 2010\Chapter 6\ in a folder called UserInterface-Start.'

Thanks

Comment: When you say "unable to get the code to run" - what do you mean? You couldn't find the .sln file, or a compile error, etc? Normally, if you click on the ".sln" file, it should load up the solution. If you hit "F5", it will run it.

Comment: Hi able to find the sln file. Load and build ok. Ends up with browser window saying IE unable to display page.

Comment: My output shows the following

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
The thread '<No Name>' (0x103c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1d9c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: You said you were not getting any error!

Comment: I dont think the error is related to the code not running.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some advise when it comes to using samples and example code from a book.

Read the code, understand what is being done from a conceptual understanding, given some knowledge of the programming language and the framework they might be using, you should be able to start a new project and type out the code and use the example code, only as a reference.

I personally find it difficult to work any other way. I have always had problems opening up solutions from a couple of years ago, and sure, this solution might be in visual studio 2010, I just don't find it beneficial.
The problem is that you might find yourself struggling getting the solution to open instead of actually learning the topic at hand.

I suggest you open up a blank solution using the ASP.NET template and press F5 to build and run and then work with the example code from there.